# Need Quick IIS 7 Help

Tags: iis, authentication, iis-7

I tried messing with the ".NET Authorization Rules" section of IIS for a particular application (virtual directory). I tried to add a row for Deny All Users plus an additional record to Allow my individual user.

It seemed to be working for a moment, but then things went haywire. I reverted the changes back to how it was originally configured but now it prompts me for a username and password every time, and will not allow me to access the site.

I get:

401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Strangely, this also seems to have happened to the other virtual directory / application that is in the Default web site.

I have checked the web.config file and it seems completely fine. The only remaining rule is the default inherited rule (Allow All Users). I have Windows Integrated Authentication in place, but that was not causing an issue before all of this started.

I even tried deleting and re-creating the application (VD) from scratch, same issue.

Somehow it seems it is locking out all users now for all applications within the web site.

The next step is to format the entire web server and start new, which I am hoping to avoid.

Comment: An update. Trying everything in desperation, I actually went into Authentication --> Providers --> and moved NTLM up on the list above negotiate. I clicked save. This seemed to resolve it partially. I can now run the application without an error and without the prompting. I even moved negotiate back up to the top and it still works. So nothing was changed, but perhaps the act of saving the setting repaired whatever damage IIS did to itself earlier. The problem now is with the WCF service that I have on this machine. I tried the same trick but that did not work, but if I call the same service

Comment: ... on another machine, it works fine. Investigating further, but this is certainly a strange one and cost me most of a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick thought but is anonymous authentication still enabled under Authentication in iis for that app/directory? Could be a red herring but is the first thing I would check.

Comment: Anonymous is disabled (along with asp.net impersonation), and Windows Authentication is enabled with the HTTP 401 Challenge. This is exactly how it was setup originally before this whole issue arose.

Comment: These may seem like obvious things but from a distance best to check. Have you allowed anonymous access and checked it is allowing you through (presuming this is something you can actually do without compromising any security). Also, I presume that the default website itself has the correct settings applied. Sounds like the default setting is being inherited in the other virtual directory.

Comment: I'm all ears even for obvious suggestions! When I enabled anonymous access, I can get through to the application, but then my application will fail attempting to communicate with the middle-tier WCF service I have (since that requires a username value which I parse passed in).

Comment: As for the default site, I never made any changes to that and it was working originally. For this particular setting (.NET Authorization Rules), the only default setting is Allow All Users, which is inherited as well from the server level where it is also the same setting. --- something seems to have been modified when I was trying to play with the .NET Authorization Rules, and even though I backed out my changes through the GUI entirely, something is still in there causing chaos.

Comment: Fair enough so the authentication problem must be in the way IIS is sorting Windows Auth. Any reason why it wouldn't be able to talk to the auth service (active directory or something). I see that when our domain server is down sometimes. Wondering if playing has disrupted a setting or something. Unfortunately IIS is so tough to remotely debug. Sorry not been as much help as I would hope to be...

Comment: I added some details to my original message since I have made partial progress. See above.

Comment: Sounds like a right arse! That is not one I have come across before. When IIS works it is great, the minute you get something a little odd it takes so long to fix.